# Whenever I try to ping foia.gov, the ip address it finds is 127.0.0.1

Tags: networking, windows-10, ping

I do not have access to foia.gov, but I have access to every other website. When I go to the website, it says "server not found" or something similar. When I do "ping foia.gov" it says the IP is 127.0.0.1. If I enter "149.101.82.156" (foia.gov's IP) in the web browser, it says "Access Denied (policy_denied)
Your system policy has denied access to the requested URL. For assistance, contact your network support team." How can I fix this?

Edit: It also does this with ipinfodb.com

I am using a 64-bit Windows 10 version 10.10.17763 Build 17763 computer

Comment: What do you get from `nslookup foia.gov` and `nslookup -q=AAAA foia.gov`?

Comment: @grawity 
nslookup foia.gov:

Server:  UnKnown
Address:  103.86.99.99

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    foia.gov
Address:  127.0.0.1

nslookup -q=AAAA foia.gov:

Server:  UnKnown
Address:  103.86.99.99

Name:    foia.gov

Comment: Try putting 149.101.82.156 into your browser instead of foia.gov url

Answer (score 0):

Your system administrator or ISP has, for some reason, blocked access to the site in 2 ways - both via DNS (hence the 172.0.0.1 response) and via routing (hence the web browser response).

The appropriate solution is to bring this to their attention and ask them to fix it.

As a security professional it might be inappropriate to suggest confirming this by using a VPN and alternative name servers, so I won't!)